# Postgresql master node fail after restart with pgpool

Tags: database, postgresql, replication, pgpool

I set up pgpool (master-slave mode) + postgresql streaming replication. Then I check the correctness of failover_command. If I turn off the network master node, then pgpool waits specified time, if the master node during this time is not responding, then the failover_command. And if I do restart postgresql master via the init.d script that executes pgpool failover_command immediately. As a result, the master node switches to the slave node and the slave node to the master node. To avoid this, it is necessary to switch off pgpool, and then do a restart the master node and include pgpool. How can this problem be solved?
P.S. Sorry for my English :)